# Possible: use Flex/Air to build a chromeless CD autorun app

Tags: apache-flex, air, autorun

We'd like to have an app autorun when our clients put in our info CD.

Is it possible to do this using Adobe AIR... We were thinking of using the Flash Projector cause it compiles to an .exe which is easily launched, but there's no way to get rid of the ugly window chrome is there?

AIR Apps have to be installed right?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, not only do you need to make it autorun which might just be part of the CD creation process; but you probably want to include the installation for Adobe Air in addition to the install for your Air App. 
http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/04/07/redistributing-the-adobe-air-runtime-installer/

Answer (score 1):

It isn't going to work with AIR, but there are numerous Flash projectors that would work. AIR needs the runtime and has to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirements and ended up using [zinc](http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/).  You can't get an AIR app to launch without installing it (much assuming that the user has the runtime in the first place) but zinc allows you to do so AND deploy to multiple environments like AIR with custom chrome if need be...Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for point me towards Zinc. Looking into this further. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with AIR. In fact that was one of the key design points of AIR, that you couldn't do automatic execution.

You can theoretically do it with a .EXE projector file, but it requires some fancy footwork, and I don't think you can output Flex to Projector.

Comment: "key design points of AIR, that you couldn't do automatic execution" -- citation needed